# Access Ext.net page through hyperlink url

Tags: c#, html-email, ext.net

I'm creating an interface for a database, one form has a button which updates the database and sends an email to relevant people informing them of the update.  I want to include a hyperlink to the web app and specifically the updated record in the email.

By using

```
http://localhost:51863/ExtNet/Client?id=1
```

I get a JSON representation of the client field with an id of 1 but not the web application with these details.

Can anyone help?

***** EDIT *****

Currently the user would need to open the web app (index.cshtml)

within the web app there is a client tab which opens a partial view using the file clients.cshtml,

then within the clients tab there is a grid panel (east region), the user would choose a client by clicking on the client row which would then have the url action 'getClientDetails' with extraParams of id, 1 (where 1 is the id of the selected client on the grid panel), this url action would display the client details in the west region panel

instead of this, could I create a url which would open the index.cshtml file with the partial view clients.cshtml open and the client id selected and therefore have those details open in the other grid panel?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the requirement/question.

Comment: Hi Daniil, I am basically trying to get a URL for a page, just now the index.cshtml file points to localhost, there is a client tab within that page which is generated from the client.cshtml file, there is also a client controller class client.cs, say I wanted to open the web application by typing in a URL to open at the client tab with the details of the client with the ID of 1, what URL would I have to type in?  I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Sorry again, I still don't understand well.

Comment: I'll add more details to the original post

Comment: In other words you need to open Index.cshtml with some predefined state. I don't think it is possible to create just a URL what would do all the job, but I feel it might be possible to achieve what you need. Though, I don't have any concrete suggestions relying just on the description.

Comment: Thanks Daniil, I'll try and put together some example code and post it in the Ext.net forums